# How to avoid "Let windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" affecting my app?

Tags: windows, winforms, manifest

My application works great, when the option "Display Settings => Advanced Scaling Settings => Let windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" is disabled, but when it is enabled, the scaling of some elements in the UI is quite off. I want my application to always behave as if the option was turned off. This seems to be the same as if the option "Compatibility => Change High DPI Settings => Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: System" is enabled in the .exe properties when the fix-blurry option is enabled.

I've got the following part in my application manifest and I've verified that it ends up in my application in the `RT_MANIFEST` section.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">system</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

I'm sorry if this question is a bit vague, but I have no idea what else I could try and just the confirmation that this should work and something else must be messed up in my application (possibly with hints what), would be an enormous help for me.

Comment: You may want to read this: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) (to the last line), check what's enabled in your `app.config` and un-comment all the Systems your app supports. Also, note (in case it's an issue) that each Container has the *responsibility* to scale its child controls. E.g., UserControls have their own AutoScaleMode, which can be different from the parent container, so when `PerformAutoScale` is called, you may notice a difference (e.g., one scales on DPI, the other scales on Font).

Comment: Also, note that `app.manifest` settings override the `app.config` settings. The new DpiAwareness settings (introduced in .Net 4.7+ and Windows 10) are enabled in  `app.config`. So, you may want to enabled these settings with care.